# Typescript - Why can't this string literal type be inferred?

Tags: typescript, types, literals

The following snippet does not pass the type check:

```
type TaskType = 'SIMPLE' | 'COMPLEX'

interface TaskDefinition {
    name: string,
    task: string,
    taskType: TaskType
};

const test: TaskDefinition = { 
    name: '',
    task: '',
    taskType: 'SIMPLE' // This is fine
};

const tasks : TaskDefinition[] = ["apples", "pears"].map(i => {
    return {
        name: i,
        task: i,
        taskType: 'SIMPLE' // This one is not
    };
})
```

> **{ name: string; task: string; taskType: string; }[]** *is not assignable*
>   to type **TaskDefinition**[].

[Try it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20TaskType%20%3D%20'SIMPLE'%20%7C%20'COMPLEX'%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20TaskDefinition%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20task%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20taskType%3A%20TaskType%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20test%3A%20TaskDefinition%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20''%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20task%3A%20''%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20taskType%3A%20'SIMPLE'%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20tasks%20%3A%20TaskDefinition%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%22apples%22%2C%20%22pears%22%5D.map(i%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20i%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20task%3A%20i%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20taskType%3A%20'SIMPLE'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D))

It seems that `taskType` gets inferred as `string` instead of `TaskType` despite the target type being `TaskDefinition`

What's causing this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Typescript will infer string literal types only when you assign it to a `const`. When you are creating object literals, the compiler will infer `string` for string constants not string literal types. If you assign the object literal directly to something that requires a string literal type, that is ok, as in this case the compiler just checks that the string constant is assignable to the string literal type.

The simple solution here is to specify the type argument to `map`, this will still preserve compiler checks on the return value from `map` :

```
const tasks = ["apples", "pears"].map<TaskDefinition>(i => {
    return {
        name: i,
        task: i,
        taskType: 'SIMPLE'
    };
})
```

Or to use a type assertion on the string to the expected string literal type:

```
const tasks:TaskDefinition[] = ["apples", "pears"].map(i => {
    return {
        name: i,
        task: i,
        taskType: 'SIMPLE' as 'SIMPLE'
    };
})
```

**Edit**
Since typescript 3.4 ([PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29510)) you can also use an `as const` assertion to get the string literal type:

```
const tasks:TaskDefinition[] = ["apples", "pears"].map(i => {
    return {
        name: i,
        task: i,
        taskType: 'SIMPLE' as const
    };
})
```

**End Edit**

You could also type assert directly on the return value, but this will disable some checks on the return value:

```
const tasks:TaskDefinition[] = ["apples", "pears"].map(i => {
    return <TaskDefinition>{
        wrongValue: "", // no error since we are asserting
        name: i,
        task: i,
        taskType: 'SIMPLE'
    };
})
```

Comment: I agree that `.map<TaskDefinition>` is probably the most elegant solution for this.

Comment: @Fenton 10x, I also added a reason why specifying the type parameter on `map` is preferable to a straight up type assertion

Answer (score 3):

## Reason

The compiler isn't narrowing `'SIMPLE'` from string to TaskType, so you'll need to help it with a type assertion. There are two options for that.

## Type Assertion at Object

```
const tasks: TaskDefinition[] = ["apples", "pears"].map(i => {
    return <TaskDefinition> {
        name: i,
        task: i,
        taskType: 'SIMPLE' // This one is not
    };
});
```

## Type Assertion at Value

```
const tasks: TaskDefinition[] = ["apples", "pears"].map(i => {
    return {
        name: i,
        task: i,
        taskType: <TaskType>'SIMPLE' // This one is not
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I see three ways of fixing this:

```
return {
        name: i,
        task: i,
        taskType: 'SIMPLE'
    } as TaskDefinition;
```

Or:

```
const tasks: TaskDefinition[] = ["apples", "pears"].map(i => {
    return {
        name: i,
        task: i,
        taskType: 'SIMPLE'
    };
}) as TaskDefinition[];
```

Or:

```
const tasks: TaskDefinition[] = ["apples", "pears"].map(i => {
    return {
        name: i,
        task: i,
        taskType: 'SIMPLE' as TaskType
    };
});
```

As to why, I'm not completely sure. Why not use string enums in place of the custom string type?