# Types of property 'slidesPerView' are incompatible

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, swiper.js

Consider an Angular 6 app with NGX-Swiper-Wrapper plugin.
Swiper plugin is called in SwiperComponent template file with:

```
<swiper [config]="customConfig">
...
</swiper>
```

To keep the component file most readable, swiper configuration is taken from a service:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';
import { SwiperConfigInterface } from 'ngx-swiper-wrapper';
...
export class SwiperComponent implements OnInit {
  customConfig: SwiperConfigInterface;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.customConfig = this.dataService.getCustomConfig();
  }

}
```

Here is the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
...
export class DataService {

  constructor() { }

  getCustomConfig() {
    return {
      observer: true,
      direction: 'vertical',
      slidesPerView: 'auto',
      freeMode: true,
      ...
    };
  }

  // Lots of other configs here
  ...

}
```

And here comes the error:

> error TS2322: Type '{ ... slidesPerView: string; ...' is not
>   assignable to type 'SwiperConfigInterface'. Types of property
>   'slidesPerView' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to
>   type 'number | "auto"'.

This error can be omitted in a brutal way, just to change the type of `customConfig` variable from `SwiperConfigInterface` to `any`. But does anybody know the better way to resolve this?

Comment: just add return type annotation: `getCustomConfig(): SwiperConfigInterface { ... `. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50762772/typescript-why-cant-this-string-literal-type-be-inferred

Comment: @artem tried but the error is still the same

Comment: You can try `slidesPerView: 'auto' as 'auto',`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `slidesPerView` property of `SwiperConfigInterface` expects a value of type `number` or a value of type `'auto'`:

```
slidesPerView?: number | 'auto',
```

According to the error message, Typescript considers `'auto'` as of type `string` in this object:

```
return {
  observer: true,
  direction: 'vertical',
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  freeMode: true,
  ...
};
```

You can force the compiler to see it as a value of type `'auto'` by casting it:

```
slidesPerView: 'auto' as 'auto',
```