# How do you declare a function asserts two arguments are equal?

Tags: typescript

In typescript you can pass a value to a function and have that function assert the value is true for the sake of type narrowing. eg

```js
function assertTrue(v: unknown, message: string): asserts v {
  if (!v) {
    throw new MySpecialError(message)
  }
}
```

However, what if you wanted to have a higher level function that constructed a `v`. eg

```js
function assertEqual(v: unknown, expected: unknown) {
  assertTrue(v === expected, `expected ${v} to be ${expected}`)
}
```

If you call `assertEqual` you do not get any type narrowing. A hack solution is

```js
function assertEqual<T>(v: unknown, expected: T): asserts v is T {
  assertTrue(v === expected, `expected ${v} to be ${expected}`)
}
```

but that requires calls like `assertEqual<'foo'>(v, 'foo')` which is easy to get wrong.

In this example, `nameOf` and `nameOf3` both type check but `nameOf2` does not:

```js
export type Staged =
  | {
      stage: 'pre-named';
    }
  | {
      stage: 'named';
      name: string;
    };

class MySpecialError extends Error {}

function assertTrue(v: unknown, message: string): asserts v {
  if (!v) {
    throw new MySpecialError(message)
  }
}

function nameOf(staged: Staged) {
    assertTrue(staged.stage === 'named', 'must be named')
    return staged.name
}

function assertEqual<T>(v: unknown, expected: T): asserts v is T {
  assertTrue(v === expected, `expected ${v} to be ${expected}`)
}

function nameOf2(staged: Staged) {
    assertEqual(staged.stage, 'named')
    return staged.name
}

function nameOf3(staged: Staged) {
    assertEqual<'named'>(staged.stage, 'named')
    return staged.name
}
```

Comment: The last example function also works if called as `assertEqual(v, 'foo' as const)`.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wE5qkw) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Consider changing the question title to something more assertive about using generics.

Answer (score 2):

You can derive the asserted generic type information from the second parameter like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM6oKYCcqIBQYAeADlgFyLgDWYcA7mADSIC2qA5gPwWpRYxh2ASgppMOVIiKlEAbwBQiRDGD4AhNKxDEUABZZ6iMBjqIAolgNY8bdok6dEAcgBqyADYgMyycA+oATychAG55AF95eVBIWAREADcPL1QAQSwMAGU+GGh3ALMARxAPRAAeABUAPjxkaBL3CmpaBmZpDGgMABMKCpEUetKYSQq5RUQMqBAsJDqp0oBeJakSDqhusMjo8Gh4WfRsKGz+aCKGyUqauYamsBp6JhXiNe7e-rFDyWuhkbGlD5weCSngwaQyx1yUHyZw8tUG7jaq06XSEzFcyVBRjguAwxQ8wU2URiu3iAKgAElUBDBOVRkR1mAupJePxBFd4TwcoJEc9kW9RAcJAN5u4fIhRgp-oKoECMWCsjk8gU8e44SKeS8UWjqexJLQcSqCREohAELwnprEAs5KwOBQnLoMO53HBEHQ4Fh3F0nIhwmFTWBzd9GpQ7i0kNb2siQogAPSx0P3BhRMkQ04q1Bqhoa5GhFPwmPxm22Tms9gxrbyKABZ6IbLIdjdK3jAA+Nt4DYw9tIGAAtGBkCxuk4K62-kpEB3G-aB0PvWEJ0ZB13J1zy+M-USdnEkLOMAB5VR4KevOtQTso0sCOySlDS4-nxtdAB0J6tyyce+9aJYIHNACNvC-I0lEmaYkBPF890JbZYj2Jch0PAAmfBIIoesn36Flr3HItU0VKAYXcTNINfR8MDRYC70QANeFCOMEwEYBsFXMtEHcGB1iwUo-xwgAiNAaLNKA+LvcQd3GMlKR1B8LzIztKOXb081AjAphmVc5Og40gA)

```ts
function assertStrictEquals <T>(actual: unknown, expected: T): asserts actual is T {
  if (actual !== expected) throw new Error('Values not equal');
}

const expected = { msg: 'hello world' };
const actual: unknown = expected; // unknown

assertStrictEquals(actual, expected);

actual; // { msg: string; }
```

And, as [pointed out by futur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16121252/futur), you can use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to instruct the compiler to infer a string literal type from an argument:

```ts
function nameOf2 (staged: Staged): string {
  assertStrictEquals(staged.stage, 'named' as const);
  return staged.name;
}
```

---

You can create an assertion function exclusively for inferring string literal values:

```ts
function assertIsString <T extends string>(actual: string, expected: T): asserts actual is T {
  assert(actual === expected, 'Strings not equal');
}
```

Comment: I'm hoping to narrow down even further. See in the example, where if I can narrow down to a `const` type then I can further narrow other types.

Comment: @StevenNoble I was updating the answer as you composed that comment. Please see the update and respond again if necessary.

Comment: I would love a solution that is in the definition of the function and doesn't require special use at the call site. Eg if there were something like `function assertStrictEquals <T extends const>`

Comment: @StevenNoble The TypeScript compiler does not infer string literal types at this time. You can find many related QAs in SO regarding that topic ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50762895/438273)).

Comment: @StevenNoble I added another example for exclusively comparing string values

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Template Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html):

```ts
type AssertType<T> = `${any & T}`;

function assertEqual<K, T extends (unknown extends T ? AssertType<K> : K)>(v: unknown, expected: T): asserts v is T {
  assertTrue(v === expected, `expected ${v} to be ${expected}`)
}

function nameOf(staged: Staged) {
    assertTrue(staged.stage === 'named', 'must be named')
    return staged.name
}

function nameOf2(staged: Staged) {
    assertEqual(staged.stage, 'named')
    return staged.name
}

function nameOf3(staged: Staged) {
    assertEqual<string, 'named'>(staged.stage, 'named')
    return staged.name
}
```

Full example at [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGBzCATKBeAUFKAfKA3tjiQM4LIBcUA5GAE4QC0AdvALao0DcxOAvsXxESZChGo02nFDz4lpEqOXoBLFol6j+vTAGMANvFKkoAWRAxIe1fAMBRevQD29KBAAewCCxSnHLm4EgpgAZgCuLHrAqs4sUMakEPTAACr04RAAFABu1JEA1izOAO4sADRQnCZISirqiACU1InJwKY5hMSqoVBZAIQ5jV2iwAAWLiVQLBBTFlYQNnYBrlnVpLWNxIIhoJBQAIImbangEAA8qQB8GFAABgAkBPAsIFAAZFCp-He8EVExOIJY4pewAR3CdnOAGlKql3F4fH4+oVimUEd5fKZ4QB+Q4gtJnGE3ajQxpXXL5FhFUoVBHWbwoaipZrApIpDpQVTYkZsk4ZbKddDC+mLRmVO6eBmoKBPHL8KDAZxQABG0CeUrFqB+WxC-2isXiigA8qEsuRakzYOIUMMRCRWil0plzTaAHQW5AYEVSDhcSo0djhciq6CKWRbUSMYDhejxT2oN2KTB6yIGoEm0IAJldluocEtdvkjuA4MhBlzyBQHvEAfDNEjJGjsfj7uTqYBhumftNAGZK6h8zai6IS2WofUNHW-bIKQnqwnpzIG-Jm3HlG2-SnMJgAPS7qB6OKkZwGCBugzORBZGgARholUzWQIG9qkgYzHrUH4jS2R5YJ5nheV43vej49maL4JpI9bgZwkj3t+v57ge-6Aeel7XjQWYPt2nCmjmUHiO+jCsDONBIX+x6nhhIHYbhmaEa+VC0LBeFKPRlEoYe1FAZhN69gxEH9kRb60B+ZHLlxaE0cBWGCXBEB9s+zEcWxiiSIJlFAA).

Comment: This approach would only work for strings: https://tsplay.dev/mMx6VN

Comment: @jsejcksn Well noted. I changed the example to cover objects as well. Please check!

Comment: Now it covers both!